# How to get one int value from an object of type ResultSet?

Tags: java, jdbc

My code looks like this:

```
PreparedStatement ask = connectionToSql.prepareStatement("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tableName");
ResultSet result = ask.executeQuery();
```

So the result object will only have one int, Integer or any other type of value, won't it? How can I get it?

Comment: What library are you using?

Comment: One would assume, from the name, that ResultSet implements the Set interface, so you could iterate the elements in it.

Comment: Did you mean this...
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
  Connection connectionToSql = DriverManager.getConnection(
  "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/tableName", "root", "root"); 

or what did I import in the class?

Comment: @nhouser9 You do realize that both classes are part of `java.sql.*` and included in the JDK?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use the [`getInt(int)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#getInt-int-) method:

```
if (result.next()) { // just in case
    int count = result.getInt(1); // note that indexes are one-based
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can get the value in this way.
Integer a = result.getInt(1);

Comment: Not without first calling `result.next()`.